# Orthogonal projection on subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a measure space and let $h : \Omega → [0, +∞)$ be a measurable function.

Let$$K = \{u ∈ L^2(\Omega);\ |u(x)| ≤ h(x)\ a.e. on\ \Omega\}.$$
Check that K is a non-empty closed convex set in $H = L^2(\Omega)$. Determine $P_K$.

- $K$ non-empty: I do not have a clue
- $K$ $\textbf{closed}$: I would take a sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}\subset K$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ and show that $|f(x)| ≤ h(x)\ a.e$ but I do not see how this is implied by the onvergence.
- determine $P_K$: take $f\in H$, then $<f-P_kf,v>=0, \forall v\in K$, so I would write: $<f-P_kf,v>=\int_\Omega (f(x)-P_kf(x))\cdot v(x)dx=0$ and try to solve but I do not get anywhere.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

1) $u(x)\equiv0$ is in $K$.

2) If $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$, there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging to $f$ almost everywhere. Since $|f_n(x)|\le h(x)$ a.e, it follows that $|f(x)|\le h(x)$ a.e. and $f\in K$.

3) The condition you state for $P_Kf$ is incorrect (it would be OK if $K$ where a subspace.) It should be
$$
\langle f-P_kf,u-P_Kf\rangle\le0\quad\forall u\in K.
$$
$$
P_Kf(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if }|f(x)|\le h(x),\\
h(x) & \text{if }f(x)> h(x),\\
-h(x) & \text{if }f(x)< - h(x).
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!
Is the condition you are referring to: $<f−Pkf,v>=0,∀v∈K$?
Isn't K a subspace because if I sum two elements in $K$, then the result can be outside $K$? And how do you prove formally that the projection is what you wrote?

Comment: $K$ is not a subspace: $|u(x)|\le h(x)$ and $|v(x)|\le h(x)$ do not imply that $|u(x)+v(x)|\le h(x)$ or $|c\,u(x)|\le h(x)$ for all constants $c$. As for the proof, I leave it to you; you should do part of your homework yourself.

Comment: Thank you again. For the proof regarding the projection, I would like to do it by myself but I do not get what technique I should use to prove it formally.

Comment: Let $u$ be any function in $K$ and show that $\langle f-P_kf,u-P_Kf\rangle\le0$.